# How to write $\displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^n (1+x_j^2)$ with multi-index notation?

Tags: notation

Can anyone explain me how to write the expression $\displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^n (1+x_j^2)$ where $x_j\in\mathbb R$ with multi-index notation.

Thanks.

**Obs:** I conjecture I can write this as $$\prod_{j=1}^n (1+x_j^2)=\sum_{\alpha\in \{0, 1\}^n} x^{2\alpha}$$ where $\{0, 1\}^n$ is the cartesian product of $n$-copies of $\{0, 1\}$.

Is this correct?

> TERMINOLOGY AND NOTATION:

(i) A **multi-index** is an element $\alpha\in \mathbb N_0^n$ where $\mathbb N_0:=\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$.

(ii) The **length** of such an $\alpha$ is defined as $$|\alpha|:=\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j.$$

(iii) For $x=(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ we define $$x^\alpha:=\prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{\alpha_j},$$ and $\displaystyle |x|=\left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2\right)^{1/2}$.

The multi-index notation is very useful for writing expressions involving several variables. For example, we might write the Leibnitz rule for two function $f, g\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ as $$\partial^\alpha(fg)(x)=\sum_{\beta\leq \alpha}\binom{\alpha}{\beta}(\partial^{\alpha-\beta} f)(x)(\partial^\beta g)(x),$$ where we define $\beta\leq \alpha\Leftrightarrow \beta_j\leq \alpha_j$, $$\binom{\alpha}{\beta}:=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}\displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^n \binom{\alpha_j}{\beta_j}&\textrm{if}&\beta\leq \alpha\\ 0&&\textrm{otherwise}\end{array}\right.,$$ and $$\partial^\alpha:=\prod_{j=1}^n \partial^{\alpha_j}_j, \ \partial_j:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$$

Comment: I don't think there is another elegant way, but just for others I think you need to explain what do you mean by $|\alpha|$, $|x|$ and $x^{2\alpha}$,

Comment: Ok, I'll add some additional information =)

Comment: Here is an expression :$$\prod_{j=1}^{n}(1+x_j^2)=\sum_{I\subset [1,n]}(\prod_{i\in I}x_i)^2 $$ where the sum goes over all subsets of $[1,n]$ ( the interval of positive integers $\leq n$).

Answer (score 4):

How about:
$$({\bf1}+i{\bf x})^{\alpha}({\bf1}-i{\bf x})^{\alpha}$$
Where the multi index $\alpha$ is simply $(1,1,\ldots1)$.
By definition, this is equals to:
$$\prod_{j=1}^n({\bf1}+i{\bf x})_j^{1}({\bf1}-i{\bf x})_j^{1}=
\prod_{j=1}^n(1+ix_j)(1-ix_j)=\prod_{j=1}^n(1+x_j^2)$$

Comment: Interesting. However, I need to write as an explicit sum for I'll need it for some estimatives and the product form won't help me. Anyway it might be useful someday, thanks =)